# access pvalue from anova on multiple dependent variable and storing results in document txt

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 100 observations and >200 variables

```
SUBJ_ID  GROUP AGE GENDER V1  V2 V3  V4...
SUB1     1      11   1    345 245 456 333
SUB2     1     13    1    333 256 345 324
SUB3     0     19    0    345 366 234 256
```

I managed to do an ancova on the dv, using Group as grouping factor, and age and gender as covariates in order to see which means significantly differ between groups when controlling or age and gender as covariates, and did I it this way:

```
> my_aov <- lapply(4:ncol, function(x) aov(df[,x] ~ Group + Age_consent
> + Gender, data = df))
```

I stored summaries of the ancova here:

```
> aov.summaries <- (my_aovsub, summary)
```

My question is: the results of boh the my_aov and aov.summaries is a list of a list. I want to get access to the Pvalues in order to see which one is significant and also to corect them for multiple comparisons.

How can I do that?

Example of outcome of ancova (numbers changed):

```
[[235]]
             Df    Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Group         1    904   904   0.300 0.6788  
Age_consent   1   358  368   1.217 0.4568  
Gender        1  196      1916   5.314 0.0447 *
Residuals   145 4366  309                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Additionally, how can i save in a txt file an objects that "cannot" be coerced as data.frame?

Comment: You can write another function like `get_pvalue = function(x){x[[1]]['Pr(>F)']` and iterate that over your list of summaries. As these are all data frames, you should be able to bind them together with something like `dplyr::bind_rows`

Comment: @svenhalvorson hi, thank ou for the reply. When I try to do: 1) get_pvalue = function(x){x[[1]]['Pr(>F)']}, 2) try <- get_pvalue(aov.summariesdf), the object try than is empty (NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better answer. There are a lot of ways you could go about extracting this but I think this at least gets at what your goal is here:

```
library('dplyr')

make_aov = function(x){
  form = paste(
    colnames(iris)[x],
    '~ Species'
  ) %>% 
    as.formula()
  aov(
    form, 
    data = iris
  )
}


my_aov = lapply(
  1:4, 
  make_aov
)

get_pvalue = function(i){
  tibble(
    variable = colnames(iris)[i],
    p_value = anova(my_aov[[i]])$`Pr(>F)`[1]
  )
}

pval_table = lapply(
  1:4,
  get_pvalue
) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```